# Why IReference<hstring> does not work when added as an item to ComboBox?

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

I need the items added to a ComboBox to carry some extra data. And I know I can  add `box_value(L"item")` as an item to ComboBox, where `item` will be showed in the drop down box. Inspired by this , I simply implements my item as follow

```cpp
struct ListItem : implements<ListItem,IReference<hstring>>
{
  ListItem(hstring display, uint32_t extra)
  : m_Display(display),
  m_Extra(extra)
  {}
  // IReference<hstring>
  hstring Value() { return m_Display; }
private:
  hstring m_Display;
  uint32_t m_Extra;
};
```

But this seems not work , the ComboBox just show blank(s). What have missed by me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share how do you add IReference into ComboBox  itemsource?

Comment: I add instance of ListItem ```item``` by ```cbox.Items().Append(item)```, where ```cbox``` is instance of ```ComboBox```

Comment: Have you tried set combobox itemsoure property directly ?

Comment: It is too complicated. I like a simple way.

Comment: Please use `Add` to replace `Append` for `cbox.Items()`

Comment: ? I'm confused, it seems there is no ```Add``` method.

Comment: Sorry, it is C# method not apply to CPP/WinRT

Comment: Please try to make observable collection and pass it to combobox itemsource, then append new item for this observable [collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/binding-collection).

Comment: Could you please explain me why it is not working by adding ListItem to ```Items()```?

Comment: If you just .Append(winrt::box_value(L"…")), ComboBox will visualize that fine. if you are trying to implement  the own data type (implementing IReference<hstring> is not the equivalent of what box_value<hstring>() returns). In both C# and C++ if you want to do this you need to tell XAML how to visualize your custom object with a `DataTemplate` or with `DisplayMemberPath`.